# count number of instances of the class inside the class

Tags: java

I am asked to build the method "getAnnualMaintenanceCost" within class StealthCruiser that calculates the total cost of something.
one of the components of the total cost depends on the number of instances which were created for that same class, how to calculate the the number?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class StealthCruiser extends AbstractCompbatShip {

    static final int COST_BASIC = 2000;
    static final int COST_PER_UNIT1 = 1000;
    static final int COST_PER_UNIT2 = 100;

    private Weapon defaultWeapon;

    public StealthCruiser(String name, int commissionYear, float maximalSpeed, 
            Set<CrewMember> crewMembers, List<Weapon> weaponArray) {
        super(name, commissionYear, maximalSpeed, crewMembers, weaponArray);
    }

    public StealthCruiser(String name, int commissionYear, float maximalSpeed,
            Set<CrewMember> crewMembers) {
        super(name, commissionYear, maximalSpeed, crewMembers,
                Arrays.asList(new Weapon("Laser Cannons", 10 ,100)));
    }


    @Override
    public int getAnnualMaintenanceCost() {
        return COST_BASIC + 
               (int)(super.getMaximalSpeed() * COST_PER_UNIT1) +                                
               super.getWeaponsCost() +
               (COST_PER_UNIT2 * ...... //should be number of instances of that class;
    }

....

}
```

Comment: use a static variable to hold the count, and increment it inside your constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to have a static "instanceCount" member in the class and to increase it in the constructors. If this is is for homework, this should be a good enough solution.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest mechanism is to have a static variable which is increment in the constructor:

```
class StealthCruiser {
    static int numberCruisers = 0;
    public StealthCruiser(...) {
        numberCruisers++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `private static int instanceCounter` variable which get's incremented each time a constructor is called.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class StealthCruiser extends AbstractCompbatShip {

    static final int COST_BASIC = 2000;
    static final int COST_PER_UNIT1 = 1000;
    static final int COST_PER_UNIT2 = 100;

    private static final instanceCounter = 0;

    private Weapon defaultWeapon;

    public StealthCruiser(String name, int commissionYear, float maximalSpeed,
            Set<CrewMember> crewMembers, List<Weapon> weaponArray) {
        super(name, commissionYear, maximalSpeed, crewMembers, weaponArray);

        ++instanceCounter;
    }

    public StealthCruiser(String name, int commissionYear, float maximalSpeed,
            Set<CrewMember> crewMembers) {
        super(name, commissionYear, maximalSpeed, crewMembers,
                Arrays.asList(new Weapon("Laser Cannons", 10 ,100)));

        ++instanceCounter;
    }


    @Override
    public int getAnnualMaintenanceCost() {
        return COST_BASIC +
               (int)(super.getMaximalSpeed() * COST_PER_UNIT1) +
               super.getWeaponsCost() +
               (COST_PER_UNIT2 * instanceCounter);
    }

    ...
}
```